# Intention to break the fast

Tags: sawm

Assalamu alaykum wa rahmatullah. About a year and a half ago, I was making up a missed Ramadan fast and did not know that it couldn't be broken without a valid reason the way a nafl fast could. So I intentionally swallowed mucus from my throat thinking that it would break my fast. Later on my mother told me that make up ramadan fasts cannot be broken without a valid reason. Also I recently found out that swallowing mucus does not invalidate a fast. Is my fast valid or must I make qada? Jazakallahu khair.

Answer (score 1):

If you thought that your fast was broken and you ate or drank other things before Mughrib, then you did not complete your fast and should compensate for it. If you did not eat anything till the end of the fast, then Allah will hopefully accept it.

A good rule is that, instead of being in doubt, you should do the things that will make your heart at ease.